# Expo Project fails to build on android due to an IOS specific feature that is programmatically removed for android devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, gradlew

The package in question is

```
react-native-peripheral
```

and per there documentation. it only supports IOS. I'd still like the rest of the application to work on android devices, since that feature is only on one page that doesn't even render for `Platform.OS === "android"`

However, gradlew clearly insists that the module must be defined...

here's a simple example if you want to bootstrap an expo project and add the module yourself

```
if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
  Peripheral= require("react-native-peripheral").default
}
```

but you'll be greeted with the following error
`Unable to resolve module react-native-peripheral`
or
`A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-peripheral'.`

Let me know if anyone knows how to handle this edge case.